# Linphone cant receive incoming call from caller without wifi network after 1 min

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I used Linphone SDK to develop an Android application, everything is good but when a caller call without internet connection it entered well but after 1 min it didn't enter, it shows network busy. For example:

1. User A have internet and user B don't have internet it can make call to each other successfully.
2. After one minute, when user B make call to user A, network busy shows to user B, but user A make call to user B successfully any time.
3. User A is registered with server and user c also registered with server have the same problem.

is there any way to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by "have internet"? is that a cellular network?

Comment: i am doing call from server to mobile network, and get call from mobile network to server. @mangusta

Comment: so your nodes A and B are in wifi and your server is somewhere out in internet?

Comment: yes. like **Grandstream Wave** app

Comment: you mentioned that the call is successful if A has internet but B does not, how is that possible?